# Disconnecting from a video call using react-native-webrtc

Tags: ios, react-native, webrtc

I have implemented WebRTC based video calling using react-native-webrtc. Its a one to one calling and works fine, but when I disconnect the call and try to reconnect again then the reconnection takes a lot of time and sometimes hangs the application. Below is the code for disconnecting:

```
function stopLocalStream() {
  if (friends != null) {
    friends.forEach(friend => {
      leave(friend.socketId)
    })
  }
  if (localStream != null) {
    localStream.getTracks().forEach(t => t.stop())
    localStream.release()
    localStream = null
  }
}

function leave(socketId) {
  console.log('leave', socketId)
  var pc = peerConnections[socketId]
  if (pc) {
    pc.close()
  }
  delete peerConnections[socketId]
  if (onFriendLeftCallback != null) {
    onFriendLeftCallback(socketId)
  }
}
```

I think that i am not disconnecting the video call correctly. Any Help would be much appreciated thanks.

Answer (score 3):

If you want a really clean shutdown I would suggest first stopping the transceivers so that an RTCP BYE gets sent:

```
pc.getTransceivers().forEach((transceiver) => {
    transceiver.stop();
});
```

This should cleanly stop the remote party's received media track:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/RTCRtpTransceiver/stop

NOTE : you might need to give the RTCPeerConnection a little time before closing it so that this BYE has time to actually get sent (try a `setTimeout`).

As to why you are unable to restart another call, it's hard to answer without some further insight into how your code manages this.

Comment: Thank you for your answer it helps alot, unfortunately the problem was with signalling server, the sockets were connecting and disconnecting which caused the video call to hangup or take much time on re-connection.

Comment: @Jeremy, In set-time out, when I put your suggested code, It is throwing me transceiver.stop is not function. And what do you mean by need to give time before closing it? Code need not to be put in set-time out?